# Display images instead of URLs of images for a column on a table (Retool)

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, retool

I have a table on **Retool** and the **"image"** column has the **URLs of images**. I want to display **images** in the **"image"** column instead of the **URLs of images**.

[image]

Are there any ways to display **images** in the **"image"** column instead of the **URLs of images**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTML** for **"image"** column.

First, click on **"image"** on the right panel to open **"image"** column settings:

[image]

[image]

Second, enable **"Render cell as pure HTML"** on "image" column settings:

[image]

Third, put this code to "Mapper" on "image" column settings:

(**"self"** refers to the **URL of image**)

```html
<img src="{{ self }}" style="height:100px;">
```

[image]

Finally, you can display **images** instead of the **URLs of images** for "image" column:

[image]

In addition, of course, you can give **HTML effect** to **"name"** column with the **same steps**:

(**"self"** refers to **name**)

```html
<h4>{{ self }}</h4>
```

[image]

Finally, the **size** of the **names** of **"name"** column **get bigger**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a recent version of Retool, the Table component has a new column type called `Image URL` which accepts a URL for an image and then renders that image in the cell automatically. Here's an example:

[image: Table component rendering an image]